Switching from npm to Yarn Berry for a React App: Polyfill Issues
I'm new to React, npm, and Yarn. I'm trying to use Yarn Berry instead of npm for my React app.
I've followed this step-by-step solution and ran yarn set version berry before running the yarn command.
First problem: Polyfill Errors
After running yarn, I encountered the following errors:
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

To resolve this, I've added a NodePolyfillPlugin as suggested here.
The file webpack.config.cjs is now as follows:
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const WebpackRTLPlugin = require('@automattic/webpack-rtl-plugin');
const FixStyleOnlyEntriesPlugin = require('webpack-fix-style-only-entries');
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require('node-polyfill-webpack-plugin');  // *** NEW ***

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  const mode = argv.mode === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development';
  return {
    // other configuration
    plugins: [
      new FixStyleOnlyEntriesPlugin(),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: '[name].min.css'
      }),
      new WebpackRTLPlugin(),
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
      new NodePolyfillPlugin()  // *** NEW ***
    ],
    // other configurations
  };
};


I also modified craco.config.cjs to include webpack.config.cjs (not sure how npm was using webpack.config.cjs and craco.config.cjs compared to yarn berry):
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const customWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.cjs');  // *** NEW ***

module.exports = {
    webpack: {
        configure: (webpackConfig, { env, paths }) => {
          const mergedConfig = merge(webpackConfig, customWebpackConfig(env, { mode: env }));  // *** NEW ***
          webpackConfig.ignoreWarnings = [{ module: /typescript/ }];
          return mergedConfig;    // *** Previously "return webpackConfig;" ***
        },
      }
  };

New Problem: Server Won't Start
Now I don't get any error but the server won't start. The console output is:
Command: yarn start (i.e., craco start)
(node:24024) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:24024) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
Starting the development server...

(node:24024) [DEP_WEBPACK_CHUNK_HAS_ENTRY_MODULE] DeprecationWarning: Chunk.hasEntryModule: Use new ChunkGraph API
(node:24024) [DEP_WEBPACK_CHUNK_ENTRY_MODULE] DeprecationWarning: Chunk.entryModule: Use new ChunkGraph API

When I try to access the app, the web page keeps charging forever.
Running yarn build (i.e. craco --max_old_space_size=4096 build) fails to compile and gives:
Creating an optimized production build...
webpack-fix-style-only-entries: removing js from style only module: static/js/theme.7754c280.js
webpack-fix-style-only-entries: removing js from style only module: static/js/user.09cef78d.js
(node:24708) [DEP_WEBPACK_CHUNK_HAS_ENTRY_MODULE] DeprecationWarning: Chunk.hasEntryModule: Use new ChunkGraph API
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:24708) [DEP_WEBPACK_CHUNK_ENTRY_MODULE] DeprecationWarning: Chunk.entryModule: Use new ChunkGraph API
(node:24708) [DEP_WEBPACK_MODULE_INDEX] DeprecationWarning: Module.index: Use new ModuleGraph API
Failed to compile.

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')

I've also tried to include the polyfills manually instead of using NodePolyfillPlugin, i.e. adding:
resolve: {
  fallback: {
    path: require.resolve('path-browserify'),
    ...
  }
}

But the app is also stuck in this case. Does anyone have a clue on how to solve this ?
Thank you for your help!
